# Convert string into integer inside array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have an array that shown from console.log(temp) just like this:

```
temp = [{name: "Request A", data: "1"}
       {name: "Request B", data: "12"}
       {name: "Request C", data: "6"}]
```

How supposed to do if i want to change the format of my array become like this:

```
 temp: [{name: "Request A", data: [1]}
       {name: "Request B", data: [12]}
       {name: "Request C", data: [6]}]
```

Please help guys... thanks,

Comment: Is it JavaScript ***or*** PHP? Please remove the irrelevant tags. If the question is about "generating JavaScript in the resulting PHP page output", it's *still PHP*.

Comment: If you want to change that array, that is, not creating a new one, use `forEach`: http://jsfiddle.net/awj0sq31/

Comment: user2864740 it is use JavaScript man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` function which will return a new array and `parseInt` to convert string to number

```js
let temp = [{
    name: "Request A",
    data: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "Request B",
    data: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Request C",
    data: "6"
  }
]
let newTemp = temp.map((item) => {
  return {

    name: item.name,
    data: [parseInt(item.data, 10)]
  }


});
console.log(newTemp)
```

Comment: You can use a `...` spread operator here in return  i guess. return { ...item, data:[+item.data]}

Comment: @CodeManiac absolutely yes

Answer (score 2):

To change the array in place you can loop through the items for `forEach` and just change the property:

```js
let temp = [ {name: "Request A", data: "1"},
             {name: "Request B", data: "12"},
             {name: "Request C", data: "6"}]

temp.forEach(item => item.data = [+(item.data)])
console.log(temp)
```

Comment: Maybe you can improve with `[+(item.data)]`, after reading: _unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number_ from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

Comment: While this works, and accomplishes a result, functional programming using `forEach` isn't intended to mutate the original array, but instead issue side effects. `map` is the preferred function as it returns a new object, leaving the original intact.

Comment: @DrewReese , that's nice, but the question specifically asks how to "change the format of my array become like this". To me that sound like mutating.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `map`

```js
let temp =  [{name: "Request A", data: "1"},{name: "Request B", data: "12"},{name: "Request C", data: "6"}]

let op = temp.map(e=> {
  return {
    ...e,
    data : [+e.data]
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Why would you use `map` **and** change the array in place??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
temp = [{name: "Request A", data: "1"},
       {name: "Request B", data: "12"},
       {name: "Request C", data: "6"}];


  let temp1 = temp.map(item => {
    item.data = [parseInt(item.data)]
    return item;
  })

  console.log(temp1);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[ { "name": "Request A", "data": [ 1 ] }, { "name": "Request B", "data": [ 12 ] }, { "name": "Request C", "data": [ 6 ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
temp.forEach(x=> x.data=[+x.data]);
```

```js
let temp = [{name: "Request A", data: "1"},
       {name: "Request B", data: "12"},
       {name: "Request C", data: "6"}];
       
       
temp.forEach(x=> x.data=[+x.data]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
I am using Array.of to create an array. + operator to parse string to Array.

```
temp.map(t => (t.data = Array.of(+t.data), t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. This is from node REPL.

```
> var temp = [{name: "Request A", data: "1"}, {name: "Request B", data: "12"}, {name: "Request C", data: "6"}];
undefined
> temp.forEach(function(e) {
..... e.data = [parseInt(e.data, 10)];
..... });
undefined
> temp
[ { name: 'Request A', data: [ 1 ] },
  { name: 'Request B', data: [ 12 ] },
  { name: 'Request C', data: [ 6 ] } ]
>
```